# Видеоплеер с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: visual-c++, видео, ffmpeg

Беру готовый код из урока
[tutorial](https://github.com/ashafiei/dranger-ffmpeg-tuto/blob/master/tutorial01.c)

Запускаю его у себя. Выдает такие ошибки

Error   C4996   'avpicture_get_size': was declared deprecated
Error   C4996   'avpicture_fill': was declared deprecated
Error   C4996   'av_free_packet': was declared deprecated   sdl

Помогите исправить.

Пользуюсь visual studio 2015.

Comment: Приведите код в тексте вопроса, а не по ссылке

Answer (score 2):

Выключите интерпретацию предупреждения о том, что какой-то функционал стал устаревшим, как ошибки.

А потом разберитесь - почему так. Обычно в документации, что в комментарии рядом с отмеченной устаревшей опцией есть указание, что использовать взамен.

К примеру, для `avpicture_get_size`:

```
/**
 * @deprecated use av_image_get_buffer_size() instead.
 */
attribute_deprecated
int avpicture_get_size(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height);
```

т.е. явное указание, что в замен нужно использовать `av_image_get_buffer_size()`. У последнего есть атрибут выравнивания, он в вашем случае должен быть указан в 1.

Аналогично для `avpicture_fill` и для `av_free_packet`. Вместо последнего, ввиду введения подсчёта ссылок для пакетов, нужно использовать `av_packet_unref()` ну и так далее.

А вообще, примеры не официальные, стоит задать вопрос владельцу репозитория.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю документацию

Comment: Это Doxygen документация, она прямо в заголовочных файлах, в которых объявлены эти функции/поля структур. Так что можно прямо сразу на месте открывать заголовочник и смотреть, или переходить при помощи индексатора (Qt Creator, по крайней мере, это умеет). Удачи.